# how to play a swf file in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-3.0

how to play a swf file in silverlight application project created in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code

```
 <WebBrowser Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding VodeoUrl,Mode=OneWay}" Height="280" Width="280"/>
```

in C# code :

eg. swf file url: http://xyz.net/evideos/tanzanite-01/7398a.swf  or you can set local path also.

VodeoUrl = video[0].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

You can host HTML (that embed the SWF file) in Silverlight by using WebBrowser control. But I think it should run in out-of-browser.

Answer (score 0):

An SWF file is a file which can be played using Adobe Flash. It can not be played in Silverlight, or you have to pass it to Flash in some way.